# Run transmission through cron

Tags: cron

I am trying to run transmission torrent client using cron.

I tried adding the below line to `/etc/crontab`

```
08 23 * * * pi transmission-gtk
```

Nothing happens.

`tail /var/log/syslog` says

```
Apr 28 23:04:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3383]: (pi) CMD (transmission-gtk)
Apr 28 23:04:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3382]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But, transmission is not started.

What am I missing here?

I tried calling transmission from inside a script and adding that to cron, no effect.

Comment: Why are you running Transmission with a cron, rather than just starting it when your Pi fires up and letting it run? The web interface has everything you need to configure timed downloading/seeding, if that is your intention.

Comment: @gsp92 When I do scheduling in transmission, it still keeps pinging the trackers for seeds/peers even though there is no downloads. I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are launching the GUI of transmission, and that can't be done from a cron. Only terminal-based or headless application can be started this way.

My suggestion would be to launch a daemon version of `transmission`, and control it through its integrated web-server. But still, no need to cron it, since it will stay up and running as soon as you start it once.

Transmission can be started as a daemon using :

```
transmission-daemon
```